# Frame seek inconsistency between Chrome and ffmpeg: example videos

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video

There is a known issue where Chrome doesn't do an accurate frame seek via `<video />` element's currentTime. (I.e. if one sets video's currentTime to desired_frame_number/fps, it may be off by a few frames, as compared to "canonical" ffmpeg frames. Typically, chrome inserts stale frames in the beginning).

This seems to be explained by b-frames. Another reason could be varying frame rates, but let's assume a constant frame rate for now.

**I am looking for some sample videos *or* an ffmpeg command to generate one.** I have tried the `-bf` flag when converting a well-behaved video to have some b-frames, but it still produced a well behaved video.

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. Not sure what format you are outputting. You want to make a video with 0 b-frames? Add `-bf 0`.

Comment: I have edited my question. I am looking for test videos, either an existing one, or a way to generate one.

Comment: Maybe you can find what you're looking for in http://samples.ffmpeg.org/